# Nested JSON and Pandas Normalise

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have some JSON data returned as below: (I cannot change the structure)

```
[
  {
    "id": "d6aca8ac",
    "owner": "test",
    "sections": {
      "summary": {
        "id": "d417cd0e",
        "notes": "",
        "created_at": "2018-11-26T19:02:06Z"
      },
      "weather": {
        "id": "7ef34660",
        "notes": ""
      },
      "task": {
        "id": "255d86dc",
        "tasks": [
          {
            "id": "t1",
            "total_hours": 176.0,
            "updated_at": "2018-11-26T19:02:06Z",
            "created_at": "2018-11-26T19:02:06Z"
          },
          {
            "id": "t2",
            "total_hours": 176.0,
            "updated_at": "2018-11-26T19:02:06Z",
            "created_at": "2018-11-26T19:02:06Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I am trying to use json_normalise from pandas to get the tasks into a dataframe like this:

```
+----+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| id | total_hours |      updated_at      |      created_at      |
+----+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| t1 |         176 | 2018-11-26T19:02:06Z | 2018-11-26T19:02:06Z |
| t2 |         176 | 2018-11-26T19:02:06Z | 2018-11-26T19:02:06Z |
+----+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

I have a script that iterates over hundreds of JSON files in a folder applying a different record path depending on the filename and this works for them all except this one structure so I would really like to see if I can get this result using something similar (this doesn't work obviously):

```
normalised_data = json_normalize(data=json_data, record_path=['sections', 'task', 'tasks'], meta=['id'], meta_prefix='parent_' , errors='ignore')
```

If that style of command cant be used then what would be my best option? So I'll have to think about separating out this particular file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By not using a nested list for your `record_path`, all of the following paths are actually trying to index the keys returned by the first path, which are strings, so I'm assuming you're getting a `TypeError`.

You must define the entire path in its own sublist:

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(json_data, record_path=[['sections', 'task', 'tasks']])
```

```
             created_at  id  total_hours            updated_at
0  2018-11-26T19:02:06Z  t1        176.0  2018-11-26T19:02:06Z
1  2018-11-26T19:02:06Z  t2        176.0  2018-11-26T19:02:06Z
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfect.